# Javascipt Canvas, Remove a circle after I click on it

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In this code I create a circle and put it where I want on canvas; I want to remove it after clicking on it and if I click again than display it. How I can do this?

```
var createCircle = new ShootyController();
createCircle.x;
createCircle.y;
createCircle.radius = 10;
createCircle.color = "red";

canvas.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function (e) {
    createCircle.x = e.clientX;
    createCircle.y = e.clientY;

    createCircle.x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
    createCircle.y -= canvas.offsetTop;
  },
  {once: true}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the canvas part where your circle is drawing

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvasID");
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```